# Wrtie a file to a new file with addition text based on criteria within source file in python

Tags: python, list, file-io, os.walk

I am trying to get a Python script that will open a few text files, read the content and every time it finds a word from a list, block that out with new text, then write it to a new file, for each file.

Right now, I can get it to write all of the source files to a single file, which is my script below, but I am not sure how to proceed to having a new file for every source file.

```
import os

KeyWords=["Magic","harry","wand"]

rootdir = "C:\\books"

fileslist = []


##blanks file and preps for new data
fileout = open(rootdir+"\\output\\newfile.txt","w")
print (fileout)
fileout.write("Start of file\n\nLocation of output: "+rootdir+"\\output \n\nFiles that are being Processed:\n\n")
fileout.close()



def sourcelist(fileslist):

        file=open(fileslist,"r")
        fileout=open(rootdir+"\\output\\newfile.txt", "a")

        for line in file:
                if any(word.lower() in line.lower() for word in KeyWords):
                    print("Word Found\n\n" + '\t'+line + "\nEnd\n")
                    fileout.write("<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>>\n\n" + '\t'+line + "\n<<<END OF BLOCK>>>\n")
                else:
                    #print('\t'+line)   #No need to print the lines with no Key words in
                    fileout.write('\t'+line)
        #return    #not sure what return does?


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    dirs.clear()

    for file in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".txt"): 
            fileslist.append(filepath)
    for path in fileslist:
        sourcelist(path)

    print("\n".join(fileslist))    
    with open(rootdir+"\\output\\newfile.txt","a") as output:
        output.write("\n".join(fileslist)+"\n\n\n")
        output.close()
```

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and I'm still not clear on exactly what it's supposed to do. Can you give a very brief example of input files and expected outputs?

Comment: For example, "block that out with new text". What does this mean exactly? You mean write it to a new file encapsulated with `<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>>` et al.?

Comment: In this example the source file is extracts from the harry potter books. 

"When Harry got his wand it was Magic"

then it would write a new file, with the same file name, in a new dir and everywhere a Key word is seen it will add the SEARCH TERM FOUND string 

This is to make it easier for a reader to see the highlighted row. 

so the new fill would read:


When 

<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>> 
    Harry 
<<<END OF BLOCK>>>

    got his 

<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>> 
    wand 
<<<END OF BLOCK>>>

    it was 
<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>> 
    Magic
<<<END OF BLOCK>>>

Comment: This will be used for 60 page documents that currently take me hours to read and search for key words within.

Comment: Ok, and finally. If the keyword was not found, you'd write the content of the line anyway? In other words, there should be no text lost in the new file, only <<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>> tags added?

Comment: err, your edited comment has made it more complicated for me. Let me re-read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tough to answer as a whole, but here's a general approach.

I have the following file structure:

```
hp_extracts: # directory
    hp_parser.py
    -- inps/
       -- harry_1.txt
       -- harry_2.txt
    -- outs/
       <nothing>
```

Contents of `inps/harry_1.txt`:

```
When Harry got his wand it was Magic
something something magic something
something harry something
```

Contents of `inps/harry_2.txt`:

```
magic something something
something
harry something something
```

This is the contents of `hp_parser.py`:

```
import os

all_files = os.listdir('inps/')
keywords=["magic","harry","wand"]

for file in all_files:
    with open('inps/{}'.format(file)) as infile, open('outs/{}'.format(file), 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            #print(line)
            for word in line.split():
                if word.lower() in keywords:
                    line = line.replace(word, '<<<SEARCH TERM FOUND>>> {} <<<END OF BLOCK>>>'.format(word))
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry it took so long to get back to you, but i wanted to understand it more than just cut and paste it. Its my first use of Split() so needed to read up on it. I now have a working script, so am onto the next phase, which is a file converter, turning Word and PDF in to Text. Should be fun :-)